# Asus UX391UA touchpad on Xorg

Tags: xorg, touchpad, asus

I just finished installing Ubuntu 18.04 on a Asus UX391UA Zenbook and have run into trouble configuring the touchpad. The touchpad is recognized but Xorg is unable to configure it at startup.

The touchpad works okay in Wayland, although I am not an expert so am unable to translate its function to Xorg.

I am posting what I think is the relevant output to troubleshoot this issue. Please let me know if any more impormation is needed. Or point me to the relevant documentation so that I can troubleshoot the situation myself.

Many thanks in anticipation.

## Relevant output of libinput-list-devices:

```
Device:           GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event10
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             105x61mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a
```

## Excerpt from Xorg.0.log:

```
[    75.047] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad (/dev/input/event10)
[    75.047] (**) GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    75.047] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad'
[    75.047] (**) GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: always reports core events
[    75.047] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[    75.047] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    75.153] (II) event10 - GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    75.153] (II) event10 - GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[    75.153] (II) event10 - GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: device removed
[    75.184] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-7/i2c-GDX1301:00/0018:27C6:01F0.0002/input/input19/event10"
[    75.184] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[    75.184] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    75.184] (**) GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    75.184] (**) GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    75.184] (**) GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    75.186] (II) event10 - GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    75.186] (II) event10 - GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[    75.187] (II) config/udev: Adding input device GDX1301:00 27C6:01F0 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse2)
[    75.187] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    75.187] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Comment: What is the real problem with the touchpad? What doesn't work?

Comment: @Shreyas Mandre any way you finally got this working? Im ATM probably experiencing a very similar issue to yours. ty